# Вызов функции при нажатии клавиши

Tags: python

Как вызывать функцию при нажатии клавиши клавиатуры? Типа :

```py
if (нажатие какой-то клавиши) == клавиша:
  print('нажатие')
```

Знаю, выглядит странно, простите. При клике на клавишу на выводе :

```
нажатие
```

Comment: зависит от того где вы клавишу нажимаете. пример приведите

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/n5utiB8.png > Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос так, чтобы он описывал конкретную проблему с достаточной детализацией для определения адекватного ответа. Не задавайте сразу несколько вопросов. См. «Как задать хороший вопрос?» для прояснения ситуации

Comment: При нажатии на клавишу например позволяется произвести ввод

Comment: Под нажатием клавиши понимается просто нажатие какой-то клавиши или же нажатие какой-то клавиши и последующее нажатие Enter для подтверждения ввода?

Answer (score 1):

Например, через модуль [pyinput](https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput):

```
# pip install pynput
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener


def on_press(key):
    print('{0} pressed'.format(key))


def on_release(key):
    print('{0} release'.format(key))

    if key == Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# Collect events until released
with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```